How to repair a broken flange to stop a water leak
A leak sat undetected till the baseboard started swelling. Since the concentration of moisture was right behind the toilet, I decided to remove it.
Upon removing the toilet I noticed a crack on the top of the flange (on its left). It was damp on and around the flange including under the tile and on the concrete. This basement toilet sits on tile which sits on concrete. It used to rock from time to time. There was no smell of sewage or waste from the leaking water.
I noticed the wax ring was worn out too. The flange sits a half inch under the tile.
As I want to stop the leak, how can I repair this myself - will a flange repair kit work or a new wax ring? I haven't attempted this DIY before. It looks like the flange is bonded to the drain pipe so I can't easily replace it.
Tools available

The basics.
Oscillating multi tool.
Hammer drill.





A simple crack that is not right though, might be able to grind it out a bit and use an epoxy two part adhesive for metal.  You want very clean metal for any adhesive to bond to.  So sanding, grinding, something like brake cleaner is not too much to get a clean surface.  Rocking toilets are not good for sealing, so tighten a bit more or raise the surface.

That crack looks like it might be wide enough to fill with something like Bondo or something similar if you clean it out real well as indicated by crip. Just force it in after cleaning. Also any home store will have extra thick wax seals which should help with the seal and the rocking issue. Don't want any movement!!

Your flange has no fasteners...what is holding it in place, other than gravity?

@Huesmann I don't see any fasteners. It looks like it's resting very firmly on the concrete. Almost as if it's bonded to the concrete.

@eszed ah, if it's in a concrete slab there's little worry about it shifting.

The crack is not directly why you had a leak. The leak was water getting past the wax ring. The wax ring was compromised because the bolt holding the toilet was not stabilizing the toilet...because the flange was cracked. Unless the crack extends down into the pipe it does not need to be addressed. It's just a crack on the flange.
Fix the flange first.  I prefer the one piece toilet flange repair ring.
Position it properly and drill through the old plastic flange and anchor with concrete screws. Do not over tighten.
Then I use a waxless toilet seal.  I know some don't like these types, but I have used the Saniseal a few dozen times and never had a leak. I am currently remodeling the 2nd bath in my own home and have one ready when the new toilet is going in.

I think you are right. As I go through the initial photos I took, I see the wax ring was wet on its outer diameter spilling over the flange. The crack does not extend down into the pipe, its just on both sides near the bolts. The flange is also below the tile which allowed the water to seep under the tile. In this situation wouldn't we have to raise the height of the old flange so its at least on par with the tile? Or would 2 wax rings serve the same purpose?

No need to raise the flange. The repair ring will do some of that.  I don't like 2 wax rings. There is no guarantee they will both compress evenly and not cause an issue.  that is why I recommended the foam ring.  ( Decades of experience with it and no failures.)

You should put a repair flange on or you can get the two piece metal ones that go underneath the old flange where the toilet bolts go. The bolts go through both flanges and will allow you to tighten the toilet down tighter. I recommend a thick wax ring with the center cup in it

The old flange is below the level of the tile. there is no way to get anything under the flange.

@RMDman I mean, there is, but I doubt the OP wants to remove and replace tile! ;)
